# How to sign Registrar contract

Tags: ens

I see decenraWeb.org have a contract with ENS, decentralName.org have a contract with ENS.., can I have a contract with ENS? I mean where is it? What is the link to sign?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry the question is exactly what I need. decentraWeb and decentralName have contract with Ethereum Name Service. Can I have same contract? What is the URL where I can sign for it?